# Multiple user credentials with array reload page

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am attempting to test 4 usernames and password by using an array. The first username and password are successful, checked by fetching the "Howdy, (username)" in wordpress. My issue:

Once it runs the loop, it fails to reload the page where the username and password can be inputted; how can I re-load the page to continue to test the next usernames/passwords?:

> CasperError: Cannot get informations from #log: element not found.

The element is not found, because it is attempting to find it in the now "logged in" page.

```
var casper = require('casper').create()

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)'); 

casper.start('http://somesite.com')

casper.viewport(1024, 768).then(function() {
    // new view port is now effective
});

//Usernames
var userNames = ['username1','username2','username3','username4']; 
var userNamesIndex = 0;

//Passwords
var passWords = ['password1','password2','password3','password4']; 
var passWordsIndex = 0;

function login () {
    casper.then(function () {
        this.sendKeys('#log', userNames[userNamesIndex]);
        userNamesIndex++;
        if (userNamesIndex >= userNames.length) {
            userNamesIndex = 0;
        }

        this.sendKeys('#pwd', passWords[passWordsIndex]);
        passWordsIndex++;
        if (passWordsIndex >= passWords.length) {
            passWordsIndex = 0;
        }

        console.log(userNames[userNamesIndex] + " account has been typed in.");

        this.click('#wpmem_login > form > fieldset > div.button_div > input.buttons');

        console.log("Log In button has been clicked!")
    });

    casper.wait(5000, function () {
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
        this.echo(this.fetchText('#wp-admin-bar-my-account > a'));
        casper.capture('pic.png');
    });

};

setInterval(login,2000);

casper.run();
```

Comment: You might want to remove the IE user agent. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24293261/1816580

Comment: This may be causing errors with loading pages. I'll try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions for that. You can use [`casper.open`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#open), [`casper.thenOpen`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#thenopen) or [`casper.back`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#back) to achieve that.

Also, you should **not** use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to do some scheduling, because CasperJS is asynchronous on its own, but those functions are only useful when you want to execute a synchronous function later. CasperJS works by scheduling steps which you break by using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. For another case where this breaks, see [How do I remove the stack overflow from this casperjs code (phantomjs / javascript using setTimeout)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24637045/1816580)

Change `login` to use `username` and `password` directly and change the implementation accordingly (you don't need the counters):

```
function login (username, password) { /* your adjusted implementation */ }
```

After you logged into the page, you need to log out before using the next credentials. CasperJS uses cookies which are not cleared when using `thenOpen`.

So the script would look like this:

```
casper.start(); // empty page

userNames.forEach(function(username, index){
    casper.thenOpen(url); // open the start page
    login(username, passWords[index]); // schedule the steps

    // you can also move the following steps inside the login function
    casper.then(function(){
        // do something
    });
    casper.then(function(){
        // click logout button
    });
});

casper.run(); // begin the execution
```

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/52bafbda707e1d2199d4) with the complete code.

If you want to track the successful and unsuccessful logins, you need a global variable:

```
var glob = {success: [], fail: []}; // before start for readability
```

In `login` you can then write into the variable:

```
casper.wait(5000, function () {
     // use some indicator that the login worked, here the logout button
    if (this.exists(logoutButtonSelector)) {
        glob.success.push(username);
    } else {
        glob.fail.push(username);
    }
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    this.echo(this.fetchText('#wp-admin-bar-my-account > a'));
    casper.capture('pic.png');
});
```

You can then print it like this:

```
casper.run(function(){
    this.echo("success: " + glob.success.length + ", fail: " + glob.fail.length);
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(glob));
});
```

Comment: Hi @ArtjomB.,
Thank you for the reply. When you mention //schedule the steps, this is where I write the this.sendKeys ...? Would you please expand the code? Thanks.

Comment: No, casper's step functions are all `wait*` and `then*` and additionally `repeat` and `with*` functions. Everything else are synchronous functions. When you write `this.sendKeys(...); this.click(...);` this is all executed synchronously inside of the step when the step has begun execution.

Comment: So it is not possible for me to pass one username/password combination at a time? I would like to pass one username with its corresponding password, then click log in button, which will take me to logged in page, and there I can fetch a unique piece of text. Then I would like to repeat the same function 3 more times with the 3 additional username/password combinations.

Comment: Of course you can do that. You can nest multiple step functions so long as they all come after the synchronous functions (like in the callback to `then` where `wait` is a step but `click` is synchronous). Have you tried it now? I meant that you only have to adjust `login` to use the passed arguments instead of the counter.

Comment: This is what I have now: (I edited my code in original Question). Thanks again.

I successfully log in with the first username and password combination, and I get a fetched text of: "Howdy, username1". But then the script stops. I would like for it to continue, 3 more times, until it gets to username4. Sorry, I'm sure this is an issue for me because of my lack of JS skill.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for taking the time to post a gist. I am running into the same issue I did previously when I was using the timer: 

**CasperError: Cannot get informations from #log: element not found.**

It runs through the first username/password combo flawlessly, but when it loops around and attempts to use the second set, it cannot find the #log element. I am assuming that this is because it is attempting to find this element from the logged in page (the page that appears once the "log in" button has been clicked, which does not have this element.

Comment: The site probably uses cookies, so you need to log out before you can log in with the other credentials. I updated the answer.

Comment: You are correct! I added this: **this.click('#wp-admin-bar-logout > a');** after the casper.capture and it logged in all 4 users! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Now this is a great way to check if a username/password match and log in, into the site. But if I attempt to pass an object in the array that does not exist, this is the error I receive: **CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: #wp-admin-bar-logout > a** Is it possible to create a message like **Username/password combination not found**, but still allow the script to run to the remainder objects in the array? I suppose this would be an **if** **else** type of statement, if username/password/corresponding page match = success, else = fail.

Comment: You would use `if (this.exists(selector) { this.click(selector); } else { this.echo("warning: Not found."); })`

Comment: Hi @artjomb. is it possible for me to add up how many users were logged in, and how many errors (users not logged in) occurred, and then have a line at the then of the program that reads: "# users successfully logged in. # user(s) failed to log in. [list users]."

Comment: Thank you that worked well. For some reason when a user logs in, if I want them to click on a link, load the page, perform a search and click on the search button, and then log out, it will Hover over link, send keys, but it will not click. I am using **this.click('#menu-item-819 > a');** with CSS path, and have also tried XPath and neither are working. The only time the click works, is at the beginning when the script clicks on the **Log in** button. Any thoughts?

Comment: I see, it's a matter of having **wait(5000);** to allow page to load. So my question is, is there a wait to create these within a function, like **this.wait();** instead of always using this **casper.wait(2000, function () {** ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I meant, is there a way to make sure that the page has loaded before executing another command, instead of waiting for let's say 5 seconds. Depending on bandwidth some sites may take more than 5 seconds, and if casper goes an searches for an element that should have been loaded, it will fail. This can be done with callbacks? But I am not sure how to integrate it in my code. I want to get rid of casper.wait(5000 and instead use a callback.

Comment: Yes, replacing `casper.wait(5000, ` with `casper.then(` should pick up on navigation changes. I assumed that you tried that already. If it does not pick up, you may need to find an element that is present in the page when the page fully loaded and then do `casper.waitForSelector('#idOfElementOrSomeOtherSelector', `

Comment: I did this and it worked **casper.waitFor(function check() {
     return this.evaluate(function() {
         return document.getElementById('elementid');
     });** thanks :)

Comment: Which you can reduce to `casper.waitForSelector('#elementid',`

Comment: oh wow, that's very helpful. now I am going to try and execute about 6 commands (clicks, fill forms, submit forms, etc.) once user has logged in. instead of casper.waitForSelector ...can I just use **this.waitForSelector** ?

Comment: Also, is there a way for me to measure the time each step takes (in seconds), as well as the execution of the total script, and the initial page load time?

Comment: The issue I'm running into is having to wait for pages to load when a user clicks, fills out and submits a form (or multiple of them). I end up with a bunch of **casper.waitFor(function check() {
     return this.evaluate(function() {** and sometimes **Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.** Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Increase the timeout. If you don't want that, you have to optimize the page, *if this is your page, you're working on*.

Comment: So what would be an ideal way to execute 10 different actions on a page: A) have **casper.wait** commands between each? or B) have **casper.waitFor** ?

Comment: It is always better to use `waitFor*` instead of `wait`, because you can do stuff faster and it is more robust. If you want it to be completely robust then you cannot use `wait` and you need to increase the `waitTimeout` drastically.

Comment: I agree. Thank you for your reply. Let me ask you, I now have my script working nicely with multiple users logging and it calculates how many successes vs. fails. I would now like to run the script from a website. I have PHP 5.5 running on Apache 2.4, but now the issue I am running into is properly "installing" casperjs and phantomjs so that the server knows the PATH. I have gone through the handful of questions about this topic on stackoverflow, but they do not answer how to properly install these libraries. Should I post a new question or do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: This is what I have so far right now, but for some reason, I am having the issue where the user does not log out: [gist](https://gist.github.com/gothamgator/ffb400e7533919e98521) what I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot pass DOM elements out of page context. So change `return document.getElementById('wp-admin-bar-logout');` to `return !!document.getElementById('wp-admin-bar-logout');`. If the provided question do not help you, then you should ask a new question.

Comment: added the **!!**, but I am still getting **CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: #post-369 > article > div > div:nth-child(9) > div:nth-child(2) > p > a:nth-child(19)** since the first successful user never _logged out_.

Comment: I added **this.capture('BeforeLog'+username+'.png');** to see if the logged in user had clicked the page in _Step 1_, but unfortunately they were still in the initial logged in page. Why is it not clicking into the page in _Step 1_?

Comment: Look fine, you're on your own. Maybe you need to check if you have the correct logout button and check that it is present in the DOM with [`casper.getHTML('#wp-admin-bar-logout', true)`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#gethtml)